# git push shallow update not allowed

Tags: git, github, command-line

Following the steps laid out [here](https://github.com/cmu-db/bustub#cloning-this-repo) to clone a remote repo to my local machine then pushing it to a private repo on github created by myself.

1. If I do `git push --mirror git@github.com:student/private-bustub.git` as instructed, then I will get the access denied error.
2. I then instead did `git push --mirror <my repo url>`, the access denied issue went away but I now get

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (shallow update not allowed)
 ! [remote rejected] origin/HEAD -> origin/HEAD (shallow update not allowed)
 ! [remote rejected] origin/master -> origin/master (shallow update not allowed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/wanxingliu94/private-bustub.git'
```

I searched around to see how to fix the shallow update error, many suggested doing `git fetch --unshallow old` but that seemed to be contradicting with `git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/cmu-db/bustub.git public-bustub` in the first step of the instruction.

Comment: You're about 25% of the way to a [mcve]. Include *all* the steps you followed from the linked page, not just the last one (`git push`) out of 4. (Note that "step 3" has two steps in it, hence the count of 4 here.)